# If I put a key in a capsule, can I get another?

Tags: ingress

To get multiple keys, I sometimes drop hack.

Can I instead put a key in a capsule and have to get another key again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can. In fact, it does not even matter, if you put your keys in a capsule.

Another method of hacking keys is entering the *"more"* glyph during the command phase of your glyph hack as specified [here](http://ingress.wikia.com/wiki/Glyph_Hacking).

Comment: And using the more glyph with a perfect sequence, you can get up to 3 keys in one hack.